# (Laravel) Trying to send email when a user is signed up, have a connection error

Tags: laravel, email, wamp

I'm trying to test laravel's mailing with ***mailtrap*** I set up all the requirements in.env folder but when I sign up, it throwes following error:

> Connection could not be established with host smtp.mailtrap.io [php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: A non-recoverable error occurred during a database lookup. #0]

The mailing is done with event listener. so it lets me sign up

> Laravel 5.4
>   
> Wamp64 server

This is my code in ***.env*** for connecting mailtrap:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=**************
MAIL_PASSWORD=**************
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=noreplay@smthing.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="smthing"
```

I'm still looking for a solution.

Comment: btw I tried pinging smtp.mailtrap.io and it times out

Comment: This doesn't sound like a Laravel issue. Especially since you can't ping mailtrap. Can you navigate to the web interface? https://smtp.mailtrap.io

Comment: Yeah  I can, but for somereson when I try to ping it from terminal, it doesnt respond

Comment: Is your SMTP port open?

Comment: telnet smtp.mailtrap.io 25 is returning Could not open connection to the host but 465 says 220 mailtrap.io ESMTP ready.

Comment: I've had lots of issues trying to get to mailtrap ports. Be sure to try all the available ports (25 or 465 or 2525)

Comment: @jakeharris I tried all of them and contacted with mailtrap support, they think I have an error in my code. :/

Comment: I guess I figured it out. When a user is created I send an email to Auth user, but there is a problem. I loge the user in as soon as it signs up but if the mail event workes faster than that than there wont be any authed user to send an email.

Comment: That sounds odd - are you triggering the email as an event/listener? Or is the email sent directly from the controller/registration service? I'd definitely recommend the event based approach as it might have the side benefit of resolving your race condition.

Comment: @jakeharris I use eventes, when a user is created I try to trigger a controller function by an evvent

Comment: Can you share your code (Event & Controller method in question at least)? I wouldn't recommend calling controller methods in that way, and if you're counting on automatic model resolution it's probably failing and getting null for the email address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I found. Anybody with the same issue should run following commands:

```
composer update
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear 
composer dumpautoload
```

If this still doesn't work, than you should try deleting `bootstrap/config` files. But be careful, take a copy of thw folder before you do that, in case they don't generate automatically. The issue causung this error is that. Laravel does not compile the applicate, each time you run it, so the when you create providers or composers, Laravel does not promise it will compile it. Which mean a code qhoch doesn't work now, might work tomorrow, because it is running from catch. So clear catch, update composer, install composer, do everything that refreshes code. It will eventually work